# Make website autofit on any screen

Tags: html, css

I have a website but when it is loaded it is too big to fit on the screen. If I adjust it to fit on my 17" laptop, when I test it on another laptop it is still big. Is there a property I can set so it is automatically adjusted to fit on the screen so no scrolling bars appear?

Comment: You have to design for your target audience.  If most people are going to be using at least 1280 x 960 resolution displays, then don't go any wider than 1000-1200 pixels with your design.  Otherwise, make a dynamic layout that shifts content as the window gets narrow.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create different versions of your applications. One for web, one for mobile and one for pads for example. A list apart has some really good tuts: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using relative measurements instead of fixed ones.

Comment: @Kyriakos an example of a relative measurement would be a percentage instead of using a set number of pixels when defining sizes, borders, padding, margin, ect.